# Finding Cumulative Sum of column with string data type

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the cumulative sum for the tickets which are only open. I have a table with id, open_date, ticket_status, and ticket_closed.
I'm not sure how to calculate the cumulative sum only for the open tickets with the data type being string.

I have a table tb with the following structure:

| id | open_date | ticket_status | ticket_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | open |  |
| 2 | 01-01-2022 | closed | 01-02-2022 |
| 3 | 01-01-2022 | open |  |
| 4 | 01-02-2022 | open |  |
| 5 | 01-03-2022 | open |  |

I want output to be the following

| id | open_date | ticket_status | ticket_closed | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | open |  | 1 |
| 2 | 01-01-2022 | closed | 01-02-2022 |  |
| 3 | 01-01-2022 | open |  | 2(1+1) |
| 4 | 01-02-2022 | open |  | 3(2+1) |
| 5 | 01-03-2022 | open |  | 4(2+1) |

I have tried the following code and it's not giving me the output I'm expecting

```
SELECT id, open_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN 'ticket_status' = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (ORDER BY open_date ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM tb
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ordering by `open_date` is ambiguous, order by `Id`

Comment: Don't vandalize your post. This can help future people solving their problems similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SUM(CASE WHEN 'ticket_status' = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY open_date, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "*id*" field identifies the order of insertion for your records. If that's the case, you can use it inside the `ORDER BY` clause of your `COUNT` window function. Then update your field value only when your `ticket_status='open'`.

```
SELECT id, open_date,
       CASE WHEN ticket_status = 'open'
            THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ticket_status = 'open' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id)
       END
FROM tb
```

Here's a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9NJ7cPoHSjMB9kF7srXFYD/0) in MySQL, although this query is likely to work on all the most common DBMS'.